# Postgres like_regex with variables

Tags: postgresql, json-path

I want to query a JSONB array using a regex filter. Following the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE), I should be able to do:

```sql
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(
  data, '$.value[*] ? (@ like_regex $foo flag "i")',
  jsonb_build_object('foo', 'demo')
)
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "$foo" of jsonpath input
```

I think it's because `$` is a valid regex character?

Here is some demo data:

```
INSERT INTO table_data (fields) VALUES
     ('[{"value": "Sales"}]'),
     ('[{"value": "CEO Staff"}]'),
     ('[{"value": "Procurement"}]'),
     ('[{"value": "CEO Staff"}]');
```

I wish to query all that have a value containing `'ceo'`.

Comment: What is `$foo` supposed to mean? Perhaps you want to include some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: $foo is a variable placeholder. Please see the docs for jsonb_path_exists. I will include demo data now.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77317468/variable-substitution-for-postgres-jsonpath-operator-like-regex

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a variable for the pattern, as [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#JSONPATH-REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS) says:

> Keep in mind that the pattern argument of `like_regex` is a JSON path string literal

Comment: It is far from clear that being a JSON path string literal means substitution can't/shouldn't work.

Comment: That remark does not seem to explain why parameter substitution fails. The same works for `starts with`, which (according to the manual) also expects a string. I answered a [question duplicate on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77318568/939860) (before noticing the dupe), and became convinced this is a bug. I filed a report accordingly: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAGHENJ4A8awD2uXHkf50eV%2B9wyiDm3eP%2BG10J09%2B0VRmXBQAdw%40mail.gmail.com

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I may have interpreted more into it than was intended, granted. On the other hand, this is the only appearance of the word "literal" on the page, and I was reminded of cases like `INTERVAL '3' DAYS` where the string must be a literal and cannot be an expression.

Comment: Either it's a bug, or the manual could profit from clarification. Either way, I don't see a reason why parameter substitution couldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As [Laurenz's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/332283/72070) states you can't use variable in that context. However you can use the workaround below if it fits with your case.

Use [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function which returns text. Then cast to `jsonpath`

```
CREATE TABLE table_data (fields jsonb, search_field text);
INSERT INTO table_data (fields, search_field) VALUES
     ('[{"value": "Sales"}]', 'SSS'),
     ('[{"value": "CEO Staff"}]', 'sta'),
     ('[{"value": "Procurement"}]', 'CURE'),
     ('[{"value": "CEO Staff"}]', 'ceo');


SELECT
  jsonb_path_query_first  ( 
  td.fields, 
  format('$.value[*] ? (@ like_regex "%s" flag "i")', td.search_field)::jsonpath
  )
FROM table_data td
```

| jsonb_path_query_first |
| --- |
| *null* |
| "CEO Staff" |
| "Procurement" |
| "CEO Staff" |